# Would a regex like this work for these lines of text?

Tags: java, regex, lines

Regex:

```
String regexp = "([0-9.]{1,15})[ \t]*([0-9]{1,15})[ \t]*([0-9.]{1,15})[ \t]*(\"(.*?)\"\\s+\\((\\d{4})\\)\\s+\\{(.*?)\\})";
```

Text:

```
1000000103      50   4.5  #1 Single (2006)
2...1.2.12       8   2.7  $1,000,000 Chance of a Lifetime (1986)
11..2.2..2       8   5.0  $100 Taxi Ride (2001)
....13.311       9   7.1  $100,000 Name That Tune (1984)
3..21...22      10   4.6  $2 Bill (2002)
30010....3      18   2.7  $25 Million Dollar Hoax (2004)
2000010002     111   5.6  $40 a Day (2002)
2000000..4      26   1.6  $5 Cover (2009)
.0..2.0122      15   7.8  $9.99 (2003)
..2...1113       8   7.5  $weepstake$ (1979)
0000000125    3238   8.7   Allo  Allo! (1982)
1....22.12       8   6.5   Allo  Allo! (1982) {A Barrel Full of Airmen (#7.7)
```

I'm trying to use Java and MySQL together. I'm learning it for a project that I'm planning. I want the desired output to be like this:

```
distribution = first column
rank = second column
votes = thirst column 
title = fourth column
```

The first three work fine. I have trouble with the fourth one.

no well there are suppose to be curly brackets this is like the first few entries ill paste a few more it may make it easier to realize what i'm trying to show you. So here they are:

```
0...001122      16   7.8  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {Gruber Does Some Mincing (#3.2)}
100..01103      21   7.4  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {Hans Goes Over the Top (#4.1)}
....022100      11   6.9  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {Hello Hans (#7.4)}
0....03022      21   8.4  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {Herr Flick's Revenge (#2.6)}
......8..1       6   7.0  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {Hitler's Last Heil (#8.3)}
.....442..       5   6.5  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {Intelligence Officers (#6.5)}
....1123.2       9   6.9  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {It's Raining Italians (#6.2)}
....1.33.3      10   7.8  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {Leclerc Against the Wall (#5.18)}
....22211.       8   6.4  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {Lines of Communication (#7.5)}
```

The code i'm using:

```
  stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE mytable(distribution char(20)," +
      "votes integer," + "rank float," + "title char(250));");
  String regexp ="([\\d\\.]+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+([\\d\\.]+)\\s+(.*?\\s+\\(\\d{4}\\).*)";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
  String line;
  String data= "";
  while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    data = line.replaceAll("'", " ");
    String data2 = data.replaceAll("\"", "");
    //System.out.println(data2);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data2);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String distribution = matcher.group(1);
        String votes = matcher.group(2);
        String rank = matcher.group(3);
        String title = matcher.group(4);
        //System.out.println(distribution + " " + votes + " " + rank + " " + title);
        String todo = ("INSERT into mytable " +
            "(Distribution, Votes, Rank, Title) "+
            "values ('"+distribution+"', '"+votes+"', '"+rank+"', '"+title+"')");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        int r = stmt.executeUpdate(todo);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Presumably by "work" you mean "capture the desired substrings for each line of example input" which can be tested by, well, trying it. Especially since we don't know for sure what your desired results are. Couldn't be homework, could it?

Comment: title result for "'Allo 'Allo" should be 

Title =Allo Allo! (1982) {Lines of Communication (#7.5)}

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: NO i don't get an error and i do not get inside that which is the main problem.

Comment: @angad: No you're not; you're trying to match certain elements within each line.  Which elements are you interested in?  Also: post more lines of expected input.

Comment: @angad "The entire line" as in "from start to line break"? Or as in "some characters and an exclamation mark, followed by a number in brackets, followed by...", or "some text, followed by some text in curly brackets", or...?

Comment: This is perhaps the format (please give details angad Soni), "<title> (<year>) {<episode_desc>}"

Comment: well look at the other question i posted like an hour ago and you'll see exactly what i mean.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360418/would-a-regex-like-this-work-for-these-lines-of-text go here its in more detail sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok, if you lay this question out the same way, it will be easier for people to give you an answer and it is more likely going to be the answer you need.

Comment: @angad: Please bring context from that question here.  Questions should stand on their own.

Comment: Start with a simpler egexp e.g. just for the first column: `String("([\\d\\.]+)")`; if that still doesn't match try `String("([0-9.]+)")` instead. Then add the "\\s+" etc. until you find out with part of the regular expression rejects the matches.

Comment: Are these movies? If so: There is a movie called “Überfall der Mörderrucksäcke”?

Comment: Apparently there is: http://us.imdb.com/title/tt1077031/

Comment: Looks like these data are straight from us.imdb.com - the third column contains the average rating, for example...

Answer (score 3):

```
/Allo Allo! \(1982\) \{A Barrel Full of Airmen \(\#7\.7\)\}/
```

Comment: well i have a text file im parsing in java and then inserting the parsed text into mysql i need to find a regex to match this string in this format and then insert it into mysql. all in java

Comment: @angad Soni - what fields are in your mysql table that you want to use from the data you got from your parsed text?

Comment: Angad, you need to describe the format before anyone can possibly help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360418/would-a-regex-like-this-work-for-these-lines-of-text please go here its in more detail sorry for the confusion

Comment: originally i escaped the special characters, but i didn't escape the escape backslash! fixed now. @vlad, yes, this is sort of a joke...

Answer (score 2):

Can you use [split](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) instead and just have it split on the tabs? Or get the [opencsv library](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) and use it.

Perhaps something like

```
....

String[] temp;
String the_line;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt")); 

while ((the_line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    temp = the_line.split("\t");
    ....
}

....
```

Comment: umm im not sure how to do that

Comment: okay i see what your saying but i need it in variables so i can insert the variables into a database and file is 20Mb in size thats why I thought a regex function would be easier.

Comment: @angad Soni: `temp` would be an array of your columns? Assign them to variables or just use the array elements directly?

Answer (score 1):

Remember the #1 rule of programming: keep it simple!
Why do you really need a regex for the whole thing?

Seems to me that you have a nicely defined tabular format... is it in tsv?

If not, you could read line by line, split based on the spaces for the first 3 columns, then only your last column would need a regexp to parse.

Comment: umm im not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourFile"));

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9\\.]+)[\\s]+([0-9]+)[\\s]+([0-9]\\.[0-9])[\\s]+([^\\s].*$)");

        String line;
        while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            if ( m.matches() ) {
                 System.out.println(m.group(1));
                 System.out.println(m.group(2));
                 System.out.println(m.group(3));
                 System.out.println(m.group(4));
            }

        }
```

Assuming the third group is only one digit a . and then only one digit

Comment: okay well i've been trying that but for some reason it wont work i get an error.

Comment: it's not the same regexp you provided

It works for me with your file

Comment: what did you save the file as i mean what format .txt or what?

Answer (score 0):

No it would not.

1. `[ \t]` would have to become `[ \t]+` or `\s+`; your numbers are right-aligned using spaces (in addition to tabs, if any) in the sample input
2. backslashes must be double-escaped inside string literals

Given that you desire the title result for `"'Allo 'Allo"` to be `Title = Allo Allo! (1982) {Lines of Communication (#7.5)}` try:

```
pattern = "([0-9\\.]+)[ \\t]+([0-9]+)[ \\t]+([0-9\\.]+)[ \\t]+(.*?[ \\t]+\\([0-9]{4}\\).*)";
```

or (simplified like Fadrian suggested):

```
pattern = "([\\d\\.]+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+([\\d\\.]+)\\s+(.*?\\s+\\(\\d{4}\\).*)";
```

Read more about [Backslashes, escapes, and quoting](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs) in the section with that name of the `Pattern` javadoc page.

Comment: yeah i know my bad i had double quotes but removed them cause the text file i'm using the double quotes are not equal so they are placed improperly for example: "hello "hello how are you"

Answer (score 0):

This is a much simpler regex to do what you want to do

```
([\d\.]*)\s*([\d\.]*)\s*([\d\.]*)\s*(.*)
```

If you need to cater for the whitespace at the end of the line as well then as \s*

```
([\d\.]*)\s*([\d\.]*)\s*([\d\.]*)\s*(.*)\s*
```

I just corrected a small mistake of using \S instead of [\d.]

Comment: is this part of the regex just for the title part tho nothing else right?

Comment: this is for everything. there are four parts(groups) that will extract the four columns that you wanted. try it out.

Comment: I run it through the regex designer with your data and works for all your sample data. I mentioned about adding \s* at the end but my sample forgot that, so I edited and add to the regex string just in case 

Can you please try this
([\d\.]*)\s*([\d\.]*)\s*([\d\.]*)\s*(.*)\s*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:
`[a-zA-Z ]+\!\(\d{4}\) \{[a-zA-Z0-9 \(\)\#\.]+\}`

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish so this is a kinda  guess...

For better help you have to give better details: Some more example lines, What kind of data this is, do you just want a match or do you want specific capture groups?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex to parse text. Regex is intented to match patterns in text, not to parse text in parts/components.

If the text file example in your question is an **actual** and **unchanged** example, then the following basic kickoff example of a "parser" should just work (as a bonus, it also instantly executes the needed JDBC code). I've copypasted your data unchanged into `c:\test.txt`.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    final String SQL = "INSERT INTO movie (distribution, votes, rank, title) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;        

    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/test.txt")));

        // Loop through file.
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            if (line.isEmpty()) continue; // I am not sure if those odd empty lines belongs in your file, else this if-check can be removed.

            // Gather data from lines.
            String distribution = line.substring(0, 10);
            int votes = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(12, 18).trim());
            double rank = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(20, 24).trim());
            String title = line.substring(26).trim().replace("\"", ""); // You also want to get rid of those double quotes, huh? I am however not sure why, maybe you initially had problems with it in your non-prepared SQL string...

            // Just to show what you've gathered.
            System.out.printf("%s, %5d, %.1f, %s%n", distribution, votes, rank, title);

            // Now add batch to statement.
            statement.setString(1, distribution);
            statement.setInt(2, votes);
            statement.setDouble(3, rank);
            statement.setString(4, title);
            statement.addBatch();
        }

        // Execute batch insert!
        statement.executeBatch();
    } finally {
        // Gently close expensive resources, you don't want to leak them!
        if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    }
}
```

See, it just works. No need for overcomplicated regex.

Comment: you sure counted those spaces... whatcha gonna do if there's tabs too?  oops!

Comment: Counted? I don't know what you normally do/use, but my texteditor just shows the column index of the cursor in the statusbar. As to the tabs, I already protected myself by saying that the data is copypasted unchanged from the OP. If you want to play for smartass, please look for someone else.